# Calculating CRC for UART transmission LSB or MSB?

Tags: c, uart, crc

I've got to transmit 8 bytes of data through UART and the last byte itself is the CRC.

Calculating the CRC I understand, but what I'm not sure of it whether to calculate it based off of the original data I have before the transmission (where every byte is written LSB) or based off of the data being transmitted over UART (which is MSB).

I currently have data divided up into 1 byte blocks with a packed struct so that it's a bit easier for me to fiddle with the bytes.

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)){
    uint8_t sync;
    uint8_t slave_address;
    uint8_t register_address;
    uint8_t pwmA;
    uint8_t dirA;
    uint8_t pwmB;
    uint8_t dirB;
    uint8_t crc;
} packet_t;

packet_t new_sig = {
        .sync = 0b10100000,
        .slave_address = 0b10000000,
        .register_address = 0b01000101,
        .pwmA = 0b0,
        .dirA = 0b0,
        .pwmB = 0b0,
        .dirB = 0b0,
        .crc = 0b0,
};
```

All of these are written in LSB format. Sync, Slave and Register are constants in this example and most of the fiddling happens in the remaining spots. Pwm A and B can be from 0-255 and dir A and B are either a 0 or a 1.

Once I'm done fiddling with the data and I want to calculate the CRC. I use this function for it:

```
void CalcCRC(unsigned char* datagram, unsigned char datagramLength) {
    int i,j;
    unsigned char* crc = datagram + (datagramLength-1); // CRC located in last byte of message
    unsigned char currentByte;
    *crc = 0;
    for (i=0; i<(datagramLength-1); i++) { // Execute for all bytes of a message
        currentByte = datagram[i]; // Retrieve a byte to be sent from Array
        for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
            if ((*crc >> 7) ^ (currentByte&0x01)) // update CRC based result of XOR operation
            {
                *crc = (*crc << 1) ^ 0x07;
            }
            else
            {
                *crc = (*crc << 1);
            }
            currentByte = currentByte >> 1;
        } // for CRC bit
    } // for message byte
    new_sig.crc = *crc;
}
```

I got the function from the motor driver's datasheet (https://www.mouser.ee/datasheet/2/609/TMC7300_datasheet_rev1_08-3364772.pdf).

There might be more things wrong with my solution, but I assume my problem is with calculating the CRC. I've tried to switch the data from LSB to MSB for calculations, but it hasn't worked. Any advice?

Comment: It has to be calculated using the same byte order as it has on the wire, i.e. network order.

Comment: OT: LSB and MSB is not really a format. My guess is that you rather refer to big versus little endian. Or when it comes to transmission of data host versus network order.

Comment: Byte order usually plays a role only for multi-byte data (e.g. a 16-bit integer), but all your data is single-byte. I would expect it to be transmitted in the listed order: `sync`, `slave_address`, ... Since you got the CRC calculation from a datasheet, it is probably correct (except the last line you added looks strange) and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: How do you know your solution is wrong? Perhaps your solution is correct, but the way you determine that a packet is bad is incorrect. The calculation looks fine. It is calculating the CRC-8 starting with the least significant _bit_ of each byte, which is how it's going out the wire. The fact that the four-byte value is stored with the _most_ significant _byte_ first is odd, but irrelevant to computing the CRC. It is relevant only to putting the desired four-byte value correctly in that spot.

Comment: Note that the CRC is calculated on _all_ of the bytes of the message, including the sync, address, and register bytes.

Comment: @MarkAdler "desired four-byte value" is unclear.  What value in OP's code is a 4-byte one?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You'd need to look at the linked documentation. The four bytes before the CRC are shown as a 32-bits of data in big-endian order.

Answer (score 0):

Some details first:

*Endian* usually refers to the *byte* order.

Example: With BIG endian and with 2-byte `int16_t`, the most significant byte is stored in the lowest address, followed by the  the least significant byte in the next, higher address.  LITTLE endian is the other way around.  OP's code does not have multiple byte data, so this issue does not apply.

With serial data transmission, there also is a byte order, or endian too.  With BIG endian, the most significant byte is transmitted first, followed by the least.  OP's code does not have multiple byte data, so this issue does not directly apply.

Within serial transmission, there is also bit endian, which bit is sent first, the most significant bit or least?  Often this order is not seen by the programmer.  UARTs send the least significant bit first.

---

OP's `CalcCRC()` uses the bytes of the structure from the lowest addressed to the highest addressed byte.  Within the algorithm, the bytes are used from least significant bit to most significant bit.

If the serial transmission sends the lowest addressed bytes first, then the OP's `CalcCRC()` matches that.  If the serial transmission sends the highest addressed bytes first, then the OP's `CalcCRC()` should change to calculated the CRC in that order.

---

**Why should CRC calculation match transmission order?**

OP's `CalcCRC()` calculates CRC after all the bytes are present in the data pointed to by `datagram`.  Higher performance code may calculate the CRC after each and every byte is sent/received.  Thus the orders must match.

At a hardware level, some CRC calculations are done 1-bit at a time, so the transmission must not only match the byte order, but also the bit order.  This usually does not apply to UART serial transmissions.

---

Given OP's `CalcCRC()` and sending by UART, I expect the proper calculation order is lowest addressed byte to most.  This does not imply BIG or LITTLE endian multi-byte types, as that is a separate issue.

Of course the important thing is that the transmitted and receiver agree.

Comment: "bit endian"?? I've never heard endian used to refer to bits. Only bytes. The bit order of a serial transmission has nothing to do with endianess. As for CRCs, the bit order in CRC calculations is referred to as reflected or not reflected.

Comment: @MarkAdler Although you may not have heard of Bit endian, it does exist and applies to which bit (least or most significant) is transmitted first.  That is important with hardware that is performing CRC a bit at a time.  [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: @MarkAdler "reflected or not reflected " --> interesting.

Comment: [No, that terminology doesn't exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803397/can-endianness-refer-to-bits-order-in-a-byte) You will just confuse people saying that, so please don't try to introduce it into the vernacular. It is well understood that endianess refers to bytes. Period.

Comment: @MarkAdler It has already been introduced by others, even in the posted link.  Endian is also used in words like twenty-one vs. fourteen.  Endian is a concept that well explains that there are simply different ways of expressing and laying out a number field.   And much like the origin of the word [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Etymology), involves the pettiness of one side saying an egg should be cracked one way and the other saying differently with the sides going to conflict over such a trivial issue.  There is no need for a holy war here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your sync byte is incorrect. The linked documentation shows it as `0b00000101`. Note the bit numbering:

[image: datagram structure showing sync bits]

Comment: Probably the same problem with the register address, the documentation says that the most significant bit must be 1, but it is not in the OP code.

Comment: @nielsen Maybe. That bit is a 1 for a write, or 0 for a read. I don't know what the OP is trying to do with their command.